# How accurate and unique mt_rand + time() generated key to use as a booking reference ID?

Tags: php, mysql, random

I am thinking to use `$uniqueId = substr(md5(time() * mt_rand()),0,5);` to generate unique IDs for booking reference.
But how about the duplication of this generated ID? what if the database already have the same ID that was generated by this? How many percentage of chance to there will be generating same IDs if I use this?

Comment: I am pretty sure that first 5 characters from a `md5` string will be duplicates at some point. I wouldn't rely on that. Why not 1,2,3,4,5 .. you can't get more unique than auto-increment numbers.  Or you just want to complicate your life?

Comment: Since there is only 5 symbols, you get very big collision probability. Use `sha256` or some other algorithm to get longer hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a human point of view, an md5 wouldn't make a good booking reference - it'd be quite awkward to relay over the phone, for example.

But from a development point of view, you perhaps don't want to use a straight auto-increment, as it could give away information about the size of the business (a low number might suggest very few customers and erode customer confidence).

Options include:

- Using an element of the date and something relating to the user to generate a reference. 
  Such as `2014/09/CUSTOMERSURNAME01`
- Using an element of the date and a random

In all options, a quick call to the DB to check for uniqueness will give you confidence that you'll never create a duplicate. It wouldn't add much overhead to check, and if you get a duplicate try again. The chances of having to try again twice would be very low.

Comment: You caught my think. I need a standard booking reference..